# How to upload an image on a website using a url for the image?

Tags: image, url, web, upload

The url should be given by the user in something like an input/text box and that image is then uploaded. The url is not hard-coded in any part of the code.

Comment: http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlupload.php this?

Comment: the link gives information on how to upload pictures from the computer, but instead I do not want to allow that, and I want to allow users to upload pictures only by providing url of the image